# Questionnaire validity statistical significance

Tags: statistical-significance, validity

My colleagues and I, have developed a questionnaire of 116 questions, segmented in 7 constructs. Cronbach's a indices for each construct are above 70%, and it is content valid. However, when we apply parametric inferential statistics, there are few statistically significant effects between demographic questions (e.g sex, age, etc) and dependent variables. My question is, if there is a direct (or indirect) relationship between reliability and validity of a questionnaire with statistically significance? Any citation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why does this worry you? Insignificance is a perfectly valid result of a test, and there is therefore no reason why it shouldn't happen with a valid and reliable questionnaire. (Low sample sizes are connected to insignificance because they imply low test power and therefore make it harder for tests to come out significant. You didn't tell us about your sample size.)

Comment: The answer to your question is by the way "no, there isn't", but that may not satisfy you as an answer. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Concerning sample size, it counts 357 cases. I was wandering if there is a reference, which I could use so as to prove this point. Do you have anything in mind?

Comment: Well, you're asking for a reference for the non-existence of a result, which is hard to find. ;-) I'm pretty sure you won't find a proper reference that disagrees with what I wrote, however I don't know whether it is stated anywhere explicitly. What I write comes from my understanding of tests, I don't need a reference for that. (And by the way giving a reference never "proves a point", only a proof can do that.)

Comment: Regarding the sample size, ultimately it depends on what precisely the tests are that you are running whether this is gives you a good power.